# Sticky header in table that scrolls right

Tags: html, css, angular, web

Can you please tell me how can i achieve sticky header for table. It lay in div with overflow: auto and scrolls right. And I supporting IE10+.

here is my html

```
<div class='table-block'>
  <div class='table-header'>
      <div>
         header 1
      </div>
      <div>
         header 1
      </div>
      <div>
         header 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         header 1
      </div>
  </div>
    <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class='table-body'>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>      
      <div>
         body 1
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is my css

```
    .table-block{
  overflow: auto;
}

.table-header{
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-header > div{
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 1000px;
}

.table-body{
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-body > div{
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 1000px;
}
```

I need exactly the same markup.

Please someone give me an advice.

Here is fiddle with minimal reproduction please check it https://jsfiddle.net/kzmwtuhb/2/

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your jsfiddle. I'm not sure my solution is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm sorry, i am looking for solution that will scroll body and head of table шт syncron. In your solution head scroll divide with body.